# ASP.net MVC 5 routing: ajax error on loading base url but works when adding home/Index on the end

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

The base url for my project won't work without /Home on the end, it returns an ajax error. How can I  ensure that if the base url is entered without Home/Index, that it will work without returning an error?

I can see that on the server side GetTaskLog is returning a 404 not found error. GetTaskLog is a function in my home controller that is used for retrieving data from a database. GetTaskLog works fine when I add /home to the url. It retrieves the data and there are no errors.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Ajax:

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "../Home/GetTaskLog",
            "type": 'POST',
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "processData": false,
            "dataType": "json",
            "headers": "headers",
            "data": "window.JSON.stringify(obj)",
```

$('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
"traditional": true,
"dataSrc": function (data) {
return JSON.parse(data);
},
},

Comment: Please specify the error details and library you're calling the AJAX request, because the AJAX seem requested from `DataTables` or similar library which using `"ajax"` as option parameter.

Comment: The error just says ajax error without further details. However I can see that on the server side GetTaskLog is returning a 404 not found error. GetTaskLog is a function in my home controller that is used for retrieving data from a database. GetTaskLog works fine when I add /home to the url. It retrieves the data and there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

Defaults in route.MapRoute says if the app has nothing on url like {controller}/{action}/{id} it will return to Home/Index.
So you need to change defaults parameter

Comment: Change the default to an empty string or just get rid of the defaults line altogether?

Comment: @JoeJoeJoe, you can get rid of the defaults line, in this case your application will return 404 error if url not found. but you can change defaults to any another url for example MyApp/ShowNotFound if you want people to be redirected to this url in case they requested nonexisting url

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm not sure what I am supposed to do to get the base url to just work without adding home/index to the end. The base url does open the default page but I'm getting an ajax error.

Comment: you don't need to use Home/Index  everytime. Create new Controller, let it be BookController. Create in BookController action method Add and add some logic into Add; for example Add can return string "hello". Now we have route Book/Add; Open this url in browser and you will see the word "hello". Part "Controller" cuts in url for beauty (automatically, platform does it).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to change the ajax url to:

```
 "ajax": {
             "url": "/WTM/Home/GetTaskLog"
         }
```